# Override =~ operator in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to override =~ operator in c++.
Is there any way to do this.

When i try to operator =~ (..)

compiler is giving error

error: expected initializer before '~' token

Note :
I need to parse expression like :

{ abc == 123 && pqr =~ cb }

=~ operator meaning is pattern match .

Comment: These are in fact 2 operators.

Comment: I need to parse some string like  { abc == def && pqr =~ 123 }

Comment: @AvinashKumar That code doesn't make sense. Did you mean `!=` actually?

Comment: I think `~` is unary  operator...

Comment: Check this page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i have updated the question =~ means to match ,it is internally used

Comment: The language does not allow you to just make up new operators, if that's what you are asking. You can only overload the limited set that has always been available.

Comment: Define a function `bool Match(...)` and change your expression to `abc == 123 && Match(pqr,cb)`.

Comment: Do _you_ need to parse that expression? Is it external to your program? Or are you expecting to use that expression in your C++ source code?

Answer (score 3):

C++ has no operator `=~`. Only existing operators can be overloaded; you cannot create your own like in Haskell or other languages. So what you are asking to achieve is syntactically impossible.

Comment: Is there any way to parse this type of string using c++

Comment: If you want pattern matching, look into the `std::regex_match` function in the header file `<regex>`. I've never worked with regexes in C++ but this seems like a good place to start.

Comment: No first i have to identify operator =~ in input string , then apply the regular expression match .

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing like =~ operator.
And there is no such thing like =x (x - any other operator).

You cant define new operators in c++.

In your case use operator ~ and then use assignments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an operator that already exists. There is no way [1] to introduce new combinations of existing symbols, and you can't use operators that are unary (single argument), such as `operator~`.

Assuming the inputs are something like strings, I'd say that `operator%` or `operator^` would potentially work. So you get `if (abc == 123 && pqr % cb) ...`.

This can then be implemented by:

```
bool operator%(std::string a, std::string b)
{
   return isMatch(a, b);
}
```

[1] Beyond modifying the compiler source code, and since this type of change is never going to be made into the mainstream compiler, you will have to maintain such a change on your own branch of the compiler forever. And that, of course, assumes that you even HAVE compiler source code available, which is not the case for ALL compilers.